# Put background image on right with 10 px margin with border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert background image of a checkout button I am using the following code to move background image to right side.

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed">Add to basket</button>
```

**css**

```
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .button {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    float: right;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url(https://finnandsawyers.com/wp-content/themes/DiviSpace_14th_Feb_13_30/plus.png);
    background-position: 150px;
    background-size: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 370px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am searching a way to put background image at right side with 10px margin to right border currently its not responsive.

Comment: margin-right: 10px

Comment: here is how to position a background image - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Use `position: absolute` and `right: 10px`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments @chirag and Andrew.

Your comments really helped me to solve this problem.

The following code fixed my problem.

```
background-position: 95% 50%;
```